# how to validate with regex input field in spring boot

Tags: regex, spring, spring-boot

i'm trying to do a validation of only positive numbers inside the request in spring boot

```
Public ResponseEntity getId(@RequestParam(value =“idPer”)@Pattern(regexp=“^[0-9]*$”),message = “the value is negative”)
@NotNull(message = “the value is empty ”) Long idPer){
}
```

in my exceptionhandler I get this exception

```
no validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.pattern' validatingtype long
```

I have the @validated above my controller class

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can also use the Min() constraint rather than relying on regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Check documentation of `@Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html). It is applicable to `CharSequence` i.e. `String` bur not allowed for `Long` which is what you are using in your method.

You may refactor your code like this:

```
public ResponseEntity getId (
        @Pattern(regexp="^[0-9]+$", message="the value must be positive integer")
        @RequestParam("idPer") final String idPerStr) {

    Long idPer = Long.valueOf(idPerStr);
    // rest of your handler here
}
```

Also note that `@NotNull` is not required because we are using `+` quantifiers that allows only 1 or more digits in pattern.